# Laravel return Illegal offset type when I trie return a model

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working with a large json that returns several data from the database and I need to return an integer model that does not have any kind of relationship, I just need to return all the records that LampModels model with this great json. But Laravel always returns me Illegal offset type.

Controller

```
public function showAllUdiJson()
  {
    $allLamps = LampModels::all();
    return Ilumination::with('street')
                        ->with('neighborhood')
                        ->with('iluminationinfo')
                        ->with('economyplan')
                        ->with('lamp')
                        ->with('reactor')
                        ->with('aluminumcable')
                        ->with('steelconduit')
                        ->with('alllamps', $allLamps)
                        ->with('ticket')->get();

  }
```

LampModels

```
<?php

class LampModels extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];
  protected $table = 'lampmodel';
}
```

Illumination

```
<?php

class Ilumination extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

  protected $table = 'ilumination';

  public function street()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('street');
  }

  public function neighborhood()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('neighborhood', 'id');
  }

  public function iluminationinfo()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('iluminationinfo');
  }

  public function ticket()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('ticket');
  }

  public function economyplan()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('economyplan', 'id' ,'street_id');
  }

  public function lamp()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('lamp', 'id');
  }

  public function reactor()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('reactor', 'id');
  }

  public function aluminumcable()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('aluminumcable', 'id');
  }

  public function steelconduit()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('steelconduit', 'id');
  }
}
```

[See the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c84bk.png)

Comment: Please share the full text/trace of the error message. It might also help to see the `LampModels` and `Ilumination` classes.

Comment: @ThomasKelley done

Answer (score 0):

Your error report is quite bad, but seems that your Ilumination model doesnt have an alllamps method.

You should attacth LampModels to your Ilumination model with a relationship, insted of doing what you doing, cause is a wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you access somewhere ticket method which was created in Illumination Model that offset error encountered..

```
public function ticket()
{
  return $this->hasMany('ticket');
}
```

if you want to access illumination->ticket, you must use this method with loop.

```
foreach(illumination->tickets as ticket) {
     $field1 =  ticket->field1;
}
```

If your still facing any issue than share your error log page here..